# How a apply a threshold in particular area of an image?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have an image of 240x20 pixels.
I have calculated an oprtimum threshold to find the noise in the image. After observing that particular area of images contain the noise like from 20 to 70 in x-direction.

Now I want to apply threshold in that particular area. Is any easy way possible.

Comment: Can you elaborate question more? Can you post more images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this might do the trick (only tested in octave):

```
bw = im2bw(I(y1:y2, x1:x2, :), threshold);
% y1 = start row
% y2 = end row
% x1 = start column
% x2 = end row
% the last column is for color images, so you address all color channels
% bw is an extract from the image I with the threshold applied
```